# How to Get client ip and browser info of websiteA and save these info on other server database? (Using PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Suppose I have a Website_A in server_A and want to store informations like client IP(Who Clicked website_A) and browser name(Client browser) and date and time (when client open website_A) in other server_B database.
**Again my Question is.. "How we store information in another server???"

Please suggest

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Probably an API on server_B

Answer (score 0):

To get the clients IP, you can use:

```
$ip = $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’];
```

To get the brower user agents, you can use

```
$agent =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

To get the datetime, you can use:

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);
```

Full Code:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER[‘REMOTE_ADDR’];
$agent =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d);

$dbh = new mysqli("remote-server-ip", "my_user", "my_password", "database-name");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLENAME (date, ip, useragent) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $datetime);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $ip);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $agent);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```